# How do you adjust the font size of the axis label in victory js?

Tags: reactjs, victory-charts

Adjusting the font size of the `tickLabels` works. But I can't figure out how to change the font size of the axis label ("Date" in my example). I've tried using the `style` prop on the `VictoryAxis` component and specifying a style for  `label` but that doesn't seem to work:

```
<VictoryChart style={{labels: { fontSize: 10 }}}>
            <VictoryAxis 
                label='Date' 
                style={{tickLabels: { fontSize: 10 }, label: { fontSize: 10 }}} 
                tickFormat={(x) => (`${x}th`)} 
            />
            <VictoryAxis dependentAxis label='Complaints' />
            <VictoryLine
                data={data}
                x='date'
                y='complaints'
            />
</VictoryChart>
```

I've also tried:

```
style={{tickLabels: { fontSize: 10 }, labels: { fontSize: 10 }}}
```

(i.e. changing from `labels` to `label`)in the `VictoryAxis` component but doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Use `axisLabel` to adjust font size in `VictoryAxis` style.

```
style={{tickLabels: { fontSize: 10 }, axisLabel: { fontSize: 10, fill:'red'}}}
```